# El significado de "no imprescindibles a la UE"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Qué significa "[no imprescindibles a la UE](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm)" en "Terceros países y regiones administrativas especiales cuyos residentes no se ven afectados por la restricción temporal de viajes no imprescindibles a la UE ..."? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la explicación! Pero sigo sin entender el significado de "no imprescindibles" en este contexto ... ¿Hay otra forma de expresar la frase? Muchas gracias otra vez.

Comment: Ah ... Significa que son viajes que no sean necesarios de hacer? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Significa que los residentes de esos países y regiones administrativas no se ven afectados por las restricciones dadas a los viajes que no son necesarios en la Unión Europea.

En el caso de la web que adjuntaste, el Gobierno de España lista una serie de países los cuales no se ven afectados por las restricciones. Los otros países, por lo que se entiende, sí las tendrán: a no ser que el viaje deba hacerse sí o sí. Ahora bien, ¿es un viaje imprescindible o no lo es? Eso ya es otro tema.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda otra vez, Tupí!

Comment: Un placer, otra vez jaja.